# org.testng.TestNGException: Cannot find class in classpath: testcases.Guru99TestCase1

Tags: java, maven, selenium

Throwing TestNGException while running tests on eclipse and Compilation error while running tests using maven through command line. Facing issue on eclipse only after run tests using "mvn clean test".

1. When I run tests using "mvn clean test", throws Compilation error.
2. Followed by, If I run the tests on eclipse that throws TestNG Exception
3. If I do "Maven >> Update project" or "Project >> Clean" on eclipse, tests are executed successfully, but facing issue after doing "mvn clean test"
4. I have added surefire plugin and compilation plugin in pom.xml

Surefire and compilation plugin
[Surefire and compilation plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foKGk.png)

TestNG Exception on eclipse
[TestNG Exception on eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfFV8.png)

Could you please help me how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in the maven surefire plugin configuration mentioned in your POM, the

```
 <suiteXmlFiles> </suiteXmlFiles>
```

has the correct testng.xml file and make sure that file exists in the correct path.

Also make sure the testng.xml file itself has the full path to the individual tests as in

```
<classes>
   <class name="com.tests.testCases.Guru99TestCase1" />
</classes>
```

Sometimes this happens when there are relative paths mentioned in testng file and its not able to find it.

Comment: Thank you Sunny for your help. I have added full path for testng.xml, but still I am facing same issue.